# OSX Shortcut to User Folder

Tags: macos, mac, desktop, my-documents, shortcuts

How do I create a shortcut on the desktop to Users[me] in Mac OSX?  Ctrl+Click does not have an option for Make Alias on this directory

Comment: I think the reason the option does not appear is because the `/Users/` directory is write-protected, and clicking Make Alias would add a file to the `/Users/` directory.

Comment: Note also that Cmd-Shift-H will take the user to their home folder (I know that's not what you're asking, but possibly helpful).

Comment: @shacker, that is extremely helpful ... keyboard commands > clicking for sure ... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down Command + Option and drag the folder to your Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down ⌥⌘, then click and drag your user folder to the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Or select the folder and chose File > Make Alias from the top menu.